# Python leave multiple if statements

Tags: python

```
grid = 0

if grid == 0:
    grid == 1
    print("grid 0")

elif grid == 1:
    print("grid 1")
    grid == 2
```

When first if statement is true, the second will become true as well.
Is there a **statement**, to skip the whole if structure otherwise i would have to split the if functions which would double the if statements.

Comment: The structure *is* skipped; only one test will ever be picked.

Comment: What? The `elif` will only run if the `if` didn't, regardless of whether the condition is true or not. Have you actually tried this code?

Comment: I am sorry for the bad quality of the code, but this behaviour really overrides the next if statement, otherwise i wouldn't ask for it. i tried to replicate it with this simple snippet, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1767754: then show us the *actual* code; your assumption about `if`/`elif` is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `grid == 1` will *not* change the value of `grid`; it's only comparing it to `1`, obtaining a boolean value and then immediately throwing it away by not using it. To change the value of a variable, you need to use the **assignment operator** `=` (as opposed to the equality comparison operator `==`): for example `grid = 1`.

Also, there's nothing bad with using more `if`-s it it makes sense. In fact, I would recommended making your program work with as simple and straightforward logic as possible first before trying to "optimize" it or make it more compact.

Also, I would say modifying the value of a variable WHILE you are in the process of testing that variable using a chain of `if-elif-else`, is considered bad style because it makes your code more complicated and hard to reason about (to yourself and to others).

**And in any case**, if the first `if` "fails", any subsequent `elif`s will not even be looked at, so basically you're forced to use multiple `if`s anyway in this case.

---

As a bonus to get you inspired (and maybe even start reading something like http://learnpythonthehardway.org), here's a demonstration of how `=` and `==` could also be used together:

```
# set `is_wet` to `True` if `precipitation` is "raining", otherwise `False
is_wet = (precipitation == "raining")
```

Answer (score 0):

The second statement will be skipped alone because you used elif instead of a second if.

Answer (score 0):

```
if condition_a:
    statement_a
elif condition_b:
    statement_b:
else:
    default_statement
```

Only one of these conditions will EVER activate. In the case of:

```
if i > 1:
    do_stuff
elif i > 1000:
    do_bigger_stuff
```

if `i==2000`, only the first statement will execute (`do_stuff`, not `do_bigger_stuff`)

Be aware in your example that `grid == 1` will not set `grid` to `1`, it will just evaluate `False` :)